# Q_OBJECT is giving me this linking error

Tags: qt, hyperlink

I'm using qt and there's a problem here , when I include q_object it gives me these errors:

moc_finddialong.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl Finddialong::findClicked(void)" (?findClicked@Finddialong@@AEAAXXZ) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl Finddialong::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@Finddialong@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)

moc_finddialong.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl Finddialong::enablefindButton(class QString const &)" (?enablefindButton@Finddialong@@AEAAXAEBVQString@@@Z) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl Finddialong::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@Finddialong@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)

debug\try.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

,,

when I delete it and run qmake and compile it , the problem goes away , but I need q_object since my class has slots and signals.

Tried:

1-clean the project " I even started a new one " + run qmake and rebuild it and it didn't work.

2- checked if the header is included in the pro file and it is included.

that's about every solution I found in google.

Help pls.

Comment: Do you have the Q_OBJECT macro in the class?

Comment: Yeah I included it on the class that uses slots and signals

Comment: Ok. I guess the header is not moc'ed somehow. There are various things to try. Delete file from project and add again (with Q_OBJECT in place). Clean, rebuild etc.

Comment: I've already tried that :( I even made a new project but it didn't work.

Comment: I am not using Visual studio  myself much, but there are perhaps issues with your build systems. How about taking a look at the qt plugins?

Comment: Thanks for your help ^^ , to be honest I'm new to qt and I'm using the express version of visual studio so the plugin won't work :(

Comment: are findClicked() and enablefindButton() signals or slots? If it's slots, make sure they are implemented in the .cpp.

Comment: @Frank , thanks for replying , they're slots and they're in the implement file using connect();

Comment: Thanks guys , I think I missed something.

Comment: Why do you use VS *Express* for *Qt* anyway? Qt Creator would be much better.